# Determine if the series converges absolutely,conditionally or diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The series is as follows 
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^2} 
\end{equation}
And I need help for taking the absolute value of the denominator. It cannot be just $|(n+(-1)^n)^2|=(n+1)^2$ right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want "series" in the title, not "sequences"

Comment: ofccccc. thanks

Comment: Use comparison, compare with $1/n^2.$

Comment: It would be better if you start the sum from n=2.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|n+(-1)^n|^2 \ge |n-1|^2.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^2} \right|\le {1\over (n-1)^2}$$since $$(-1)^n\ge -1$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
 S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^2} 
\end{equation} S is divergent because at $n=1$, $S\rightarrow -\infty$.

If the summation is started from $n=2$ we get the followings:

\begin{equation}
 S^*=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+(-1)^{n+1})^2} 
\end{equation}

After separation the even and odd terms we have that:

$S^*=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4k^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\zeta(2)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$

Known that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}-1 $

So \begin{equation} S^*=1-\frac{\pi^2}{12} \end{equation}

The sum is absolutely convergent because:

$|S^*|=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4k^2}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\zeta(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{8}-1=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$